# DropDownList with same "Value" and OnTextChange Event

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

In an `ASP.NET` project I have a `DropDownList` with three values and two of them

**must have the same ValueField:**

> - "1","Yellow"
> - "1", "Red"
> - "2", "Blue"

The problem is that on the `"SelectedIndexChanged"` event does not fire when I change from "Yellow" to "Red" because the two options have the same Value.

Is there any way to make an eventRise when I change to "Red" to `"Yellow"`?

I also tried the `TextChanged event`, but it rises when both `Value and Text change`.

Note: I cannot call the event handler from the PageLoad

Comment: put your code dropdownlist

Comment: why you need same value??

Comment: I need because adding a new value would be impacting for all the system.

Comment: this time only one option you can use primary key column

Comment: otherwise you change value in all of the system

Comment: did you enable `AutoPostBack="true"` in dropdownlist

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to make the values unique by adding an index: `Value="1_0"`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Yellow" Value="1_0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Red" Value="1_1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Blue" Value="2_2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Or add them programatically

```
for (int i = 0; i < DropDownList1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    DropDownList1.Items[i].Value = DropDownList1.Items[i].Value + "_" + i;
}
```

And then in code behind split the `SelectedValue` to get the correct color.

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Split('_')[0];
}
```